# Running tests from RubyMine?

Tags: ruby, rubymine

I am able to to run/debug simple scripts from RubyMine, but I encounter an error when running existent tests.

My Rakefile contains:

```
Rake::TestTask.new(:test) do |t|
  t.libs << "test"
  t.libs << "lib"
  t.test_files = FileList["test/**/*_test.rb"]
end
```

My tests run as expected when I execute:

```
bundle exec rake test
```

But when I try to run a test from RubyMine, which contains `require 'test_helper` on its first line, I get the below error:

> /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- test_helper (LoadError)

Can I set the libs value when running form RubyMine, similar to in my Rakefile?

*Edit*

After setting my working directory to *myproject*/tests and adding `-Itest` to my Ruby arguments, the `require test_helper` line succeeds. However, RubyMine still gives the LoadError on my next require line, which requires a local dependency from a gem defined in my Gemfile. Again, the test runs as expected from the terminal, how do I configure RubyMine to use the gems defined in my Gemfile?